# Use $interval on a service method isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I'm building a mobile web app which detects if user browser has access to internet or not.

I'm using AngularJS framework to achieve this. I call a service method from AppData each 1000 ms to test user connexion with an ajax request.

PicController binds the result to my html view.

My idea is to create a service AppData which will store general properties and methods of my app.

This code simply doesn't work, I guess it's wrong way, could some expert tell me how to do ?

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'online' of undefined
    at isOnline (pictureViewer.js:24)
```

Code:

```
'use strict';

var picApp = angular.module('pictureViewerApp',[]);

picApp.run(['$interval','AppData', function($interval, AppData){
    $interval(AppData.isOnline,1000);
}]);

picApp.controller("PicController",['$scope', 'AppData', function($scope, AppData){
    $scope.online = AppData.online;
}]);

picApp.factory('AppData', ['$http', function($http) {
    var AppData = {};
    AppData.online = false;
    AppData.isOnline = function() {
        var appData = this;
        $http.get('online.php').
            success(function(data) {
                appData.online = true;
            }).
            error(function() {
                appData.online = false;
            });
        console.log("AppData.online = ", appData.online);
    };
    return AppData;
}]);
```

**Edit:**
The error happens at this line exactly:

```
console.log("AppData.online = ", appData.online);
```

**Edit 2:**
If I call my method one time it works fine, the problem happens only when I'm using $interval to call it.

Thanks

Comment: bad code..you shouldn't use jquery ajax, you should use `$http` instead

Comment: thanks for suggestion I will try, but it won't fix my current errors :/

Comment: the error you are getting which is inside controller or service?

Comment: inside the service, the method does not find this.online.

Comment: You forgot bind on $interval. Check my updated answer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your view will not update, since your `$scope.online` is binding to a `value`, not a `reference` (object/array/function).

2) You can't pass ´AppData.isOnline´ as argument without using bind (check browser compatibility)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Check this working example:

```js
var picApp = angular.module('pictureViewerApp',[]);

picApp.run(function(AppData, $interval) {
  $interval(AppData.isOnline.bind(AppData), 1000);
  /*
  //Is same as
  $interval(function(){
    AppData.isOnline();
  }, 1000);*/
});

picApp.controller("PicController",['$scope', 'AppData', function($scope, AppData){
    $scope.AppData = AppData;
}]);

picApp.factory('AppData', function($q) {
    var AppData = {
      online: false
      
    };
    
    AppData.isOnline = function() {      
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      
      // TODO: Use $http to load.
      this.online = true;
      deferred.resolve(true);
      
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  
    
    return AppData;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pictureViewerApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="PicController">
    <p>User is online? {{AppData.online}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: But it may fix errors that I would met later thanks. .done and .fail are asynchronous, so console.log is called in first and I get an error here currently.

Comment: It does not refresh each 1000 ms :(

Comment: In my code if I just call the method one time it work fine, the problem happens when I use $interval.

Comment: If you bind `$scope.online` to a `boolean`, your view will not update.

You must bind to an `object` or a `function`. Now i'm using $interval, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest use interceptors. Just chceck if it is proper request, and if it got proper header, set ok, if its not thur `$injector` put rootScope, or even broadcast this event. Then service use like requester

```
picApp.service('AppData', function($http) {
    this.getOnlineResponse = function(){
        $http(someApiRequestPath);
       }
     return this;
});
```

Comment: I think the error has nothing to deal with the request.